# How can i get the value of a variable from PHP to AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs

=== Lets just say i already have setup my App and Controller ====

### test.phtml

```
 $var = "Welcome";
```

### myangular.js

```
$scope.var = "<?php $var; ?>" //not sure about this part

console.log(var)
```

---

MY PROBLEM is that, i cant display the console.log(var) it says "undefined?"

Is it possible? i want to pass the PHP VARIABLE to ANGULAR onload, right when page is loaded..

BTW im using phalcon framework

Answer (score 2):

you need to echo the variable:

```
$scope.var = "<? echo $var; ?>"
```

or in a shorter way:

```
$scope.var = "<?=$var; ?>"
```

technicly both are the same.

Comment: Although this is a simple and effective way, most of the time your js will be written inside independent js files. In those cases you'll need to assign to a global javascript variable (to your index.html) rather than to the script directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest exposing a public API from your PHP application and then calling it using the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service in angular-js.

```
$http.get('APIURL', {cache: true})
     .success(function(data){...})
     .error(function(data){});
```